# How to delete a Minecraft profile on new 2017 launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

How do I delete a Minecraft profile on new 2017 launcher?

Answer (score 1):

To delete a profile, first go to Launch options. Click on the profile you wish to delete and in the top right there should be a delete button. Press that to delete the profile.

[image]

Comment: Do you know of a way to delete the "Latest Release" and "Latest Snapshot" profiles?

Comment: @theonlygusti As far as I'm aware, these are default profiles and can't be deleted. If you're really desperate I could probably find some hack to make them disappear but that seems a lot of effort when you could just ignore them.